# Perl: How to emulate Ruby's "include/extend" mechanism?

Tags: ruby, perl, include, extend, emulation

How I can emulate in my Perl code things like Ruby's "include"/"extend" mechanism?

Let's take for example the following code in Ruby:

```
module ActiveRecord
  class Base

    class << self
      #...
    end

    #...
  end

  Base.class_eval do
    include ActiveRecord::Persistence
    extend ActiveModel::Naming
    extend QueryCache::ClassMethods
    extend ActiveSupport::Benchmarkable
    extend ActiveSupport::DescendantsTracker

    include ActiveModel::Conversion
    include Validations
    extend CounterCache
    include Locking::Optimistic, Locking::Pessimistic
    include AttributeMethods
    ...
  end
end
```

It leads me to ask this question, because I can't find any clear idea during several days of researching. So, maybe there exists some good way to organize it in Perl?

Answer (score 7):

That looks like *traits/mixins* vs *inheritance*, both done at runtime.

The traits/mixins parts are covered by a Perl6 concept called a Role.

How to implement in Perl 5? Look no further than [Moose](http://moose.iinteractive.com/) (see also the [perldoc for Moose](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose))

I believe it started as a proving ground for the OO/meta language support features headed for Perl 6, but in Perl 5. Now it has taken on a life of its own and a great many CPAN packages have dependencies on Moose.

Moose implements a wide variety of Object Oriented language constructs (from a few different OO paradigms) and is very extensible.

An explanation of the concepts in Moose and how they map to constructs in other languages can be found in the [Concepts section of the Moose manual](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose%3a%3aManual%3a%3aConcepts)

Additionally, the `Moose` and `MooseX` namespaces on CPAN are chock full of complimentary (or experimental) packages to add support for even more OO constructs.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a small example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.014;

package My::Quoted {
    use Role::Tiny;
    sub quoted_name {
        my $self = shift;
        return sprintf q{"%s"}, $self->name;
    }
}

package My::One {
    use Moo;
    has name => (is => 'ro');

    sub greet {
        my $self = shift;
        return sprintf 'Hello %s', $self->name;
    }
}

package My::Two {
    use Moo;

    extends 'My::One';
    with 'My::Quoted';

    sub greet {
        my $self = shift;
        return sprintf 'Merhaba %s', $self->quoted_name;
    }
}

package main {
    run('Perl');
    sub run {
        my $name = shift;

        my $x = My::Two->new({name => $name});
        my $y = My::One->new({name => $name});

        say $_->greet for $x, $y;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Merhaba "Perl"
Hello Perl
```

Answer (score 1):

A *literal* translation of this code to Perl/Moose would (kinda) look like this:

```
package ActiveRecord::Base;
use Moose;
use namespace::autoclean;

with qw(
    ActiveRecord::Persistence
    ActiveModel::Naming
    QueryCache::ClassMethods
    ActiveSupport::Benchmarkable
    ActiveSupport::DescendantsTracker
    ActiveModel::Conversion
    Validations
    CounterCache
    Locking::Optimistic
    Locking::Pessimistic
    AttributeMethods
);

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
1;
```

Above uses [Moose Roles](https://metacpan.org/module/Moose%3a%3aRole) which are equivalent to Ruby's mixins.

In Ruby `include` is for mixing in instance methods whereas `extend` is for class mixins.  In Perl all methods can be called by class or instance so roles are added using `with`.